# Perl Regex unable to select word with Special character $

Tags: regex, perl

I tried to split a string into words (one of the words has the special character `$`) , but the split didn't work. I want to split the string below into "Test" "Str$ing"

```
$test = "Test Str$ing";

my @words = split(" ",$test);

print "@words";

print "-------1End------------\n";


foreach my $str (split /(\s)+/, $test) {        
    print "$str\n";
}

print "-------End------------\n";
```

I executed the above code and got the below result, and, as you can see, the 2nd word is only half there:

```
Test Str
-------1End------------
Test

Str
-------End------------
```

Any help on this?

Comment: You ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write. This measure would have revealed the problem immediately.

Comment: You *should* do both of those things. The fact that it's *not* a "must" is sort of the problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Perl, a dollar sign inside a double-quoted string triggers interpolation.  So this assignment:

```
$test = "Test Str$ing";
```

sets `$test` to the string `Test Str` followed by the value of the variable `$ing`.  If `$ing` is not set (and you don't have strictures enabled, which would cause the program to fail at this point), the result is just `Test Str`.

To get a literal dollar sign you have to escape it with a backslash, or use single quotes instead:

```
$test = "Test Str\$ing";
# or
$test = 'Test Str$ing';
```

In any case, the first line in your program, after the `#!` anyway, should be `use strict;`.  Then Perl will catch these errors and blow up instead of silently letting you shoot yourself in the foot. For good measure, you should add `use warnings;` too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$test = "Test Str$ing";
```

Watch what happens when I try to run the above:

```
Global symbol "$test" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $test"?) at foo.pl line 5.   
Global symbol "$ing" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $ing"?) at foo.pl line 5.
Execution of foo.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Your program should look more like this, with minimal changes to pass strict:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = 'Test Str$ing';

my @words = split ' ', $test;

print "@words";

print "-------1End------------\n";

foreach my $str (split /(\s)+/, $test) {
  print "$str\n";
}

print "-------End------------\n";
```

That still seems odd to me, as you're printing all the words on a single line without a newline before the `1End` sentinel, and then printing each of them on a line with blank lines between (not really blank, though - containing the whitespace from the original string). But if that's what you want, the above works.  Output:

```
Test Str$ing-------1End------------
Test

Str$ing
-------End------------
```

Comment: Thanks Accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple quotation marks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$test = 'Test Str$ing';

my @words = split(' ',$test);

print "@words";
```

Otherwise Perl considers `$ing` to be a variable (which is empty).

Comment: With the single quotes still i'm getting the result as 
Test Str

Comment: Then you changed the wrong quotes.  It's the ones around `Test Str$ing` that need to be singles.

Comment: Around the string!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to assign data to a variable is by using single quotes.
Ex:

```
my $var_name = 'TEST MESSAGE';
```

If the data which consists of variable and this is to be assigned to another variable then use double quotes. Data in double quotes will interpolated by PERL.
Ex:

```
my $var1 = 'TEST';
my $var2 = "$var1 MESSAGE";
```